# SQL Server - Get data from two tables and within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see my table and data below -

```
DECLARE @test1 TABLE (Ref nvarchar(10) NULL, Dates datetime NULL);
INSERT INTO @test1(Ref, Dates) 
VALUES 
('R1', '2018-10-26'),
('R2', '2018-10-26'),
('R5', null);

DECLARE @test2 TABLE (P_Ref nvarchar(50) null, Name nvarchar(50) null);
INSERT INTO @test2(P_Ref, Name)
VALUES 
('R1', 'N1'),
('R1', 'N2'),
('R2', 'N1'),
('R2', 'N2'),
('R3', 'N1'),
('R3', 'N2'),
('R4', 'N2'),
('R5', 'N3'),
('R6', 'N3'),
('R7', 'N4');
```

I am using `where` condition in table 1 `@test1`, it's `Ref` column join with table 2 `@test2` `P_Ref` column. 
I want all the related data from both tables as well as all the matches `Name` from `@test2` table

My query is -

```
select t1.Ref, t2.P_Ref, t2.Name from
@test1 t1
right join @test2 t2
on t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
where t1.Dates is not null
```

The output I am getting -

```
   Ref    P_Ref    Name
    R1      R1      N1
    R1      R1      N2
    R2      R2      N1
    R2      R2      N2
```

I am looking below output -

```
   Ref    P_Ref    Name
    R1      R1      N1
    R1      R1      N2
    R2      R2      N1
    R2      R2      N2
    NULL    R3      N1
    NULL    R3      N2
    NULL    R4      N2
```

Could someone please help me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you get `R5` , `R6`,`R7`  in your expect result

Comment: @D-Shih, because `Ref` `R1` and `R2` has name `N1` and `N2`, but `R5`, `R6` has different name and this `R1` and `R2` coming from `@test1` tables `where` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query

```
SELECT t1.Ref, t2.P_Ref, t2.Name
FROM @test1 t1
RIGHT JOIN @test2 t2 ON t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
WHERE t2.Name IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT t2.Name
    FROM @test1 t1
    JOIN @test2 t2 ON t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
    WHERE t1.Dates IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Comment: The DISTINCT in your subquery here does nothing but waste the query planner's time.  Compare execution plans and you'll find that to be the case (unless the planner optimizes it out, which is also possible).

Comment: @Bacon Bits - Yes, you're right. Thank you for your comment! I've tried another query and found that the optimizer can use `Distinct Sort`, and I've got two absolutely equals plans for subqueries with `DISTINCT` and without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
select t1.Ref, t2.P_Ref, t2.Name from
@test1 t1 right join @test2 t2
on t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
where Name in ('N1', 'N2')
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are large number of records expected whose `Dates` may not be `NULL` then an optimized option will be as below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValidRecords') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ValidRecords

SELECT DISTINCT t2.[Name]
INTO #ValidRecords
FROM @test1 t1
JOIN @test2 t2 ON t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
WHERE t1.Dates IS NOT NULL

SELECT Ref,
t2.P_Ref,
t2.[Name]
FROM @test1 t1
RIGHT JOIN @test2 t2 ON t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
INNER JOIN #ValidRecords vr ON vr.[Name] = t2.[Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your WHERE clause is turning your outer join into an implicit inner join.  To filter the outer table, it's usually easiest to move the filter condition for the outer table to the join condition.

```
select t1.Ref, t2.P_Ref, t2.Name from
@test1 t1
right join @test2 t2
    on  t1.Ref = t2.P_Ref
    and t1.Dates is not null
```

Comment: This query is not giving expected output. In this scenario I think even if you will move your condition in join condition then also `RIGHT` tables all the records will be fetched.